# Windows 8 shortcut tile not shown

Tags: c#, windows-8

Windows 8 shortcut tile is not shown in the start screen for my application. My application has three shortcuts, but only two of them are shown in the start screen. But the third icon reappears when I reinstall my application.

Comment: Is this reproduce everytime for the same shortcut?

Comment: yes Vikram. This issue is there every time I install the application for the first time. But its gone when I reinstall. It again appears when I uninstall my application and install it.

Comment: Have you placed your application shortscuts in "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" folder?

Comment: yes, the application installer places the shortcuts in the "Programs" folder

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem in the meantime? I'm facing exactly the same problem with one shortcut (of many others that are appearing correctly) for my application on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 2):

Can you see if this post is helpful. http://www.askvg.com/fix-desktop-tile-missing-from-windows-8-start-screen-cant-add-from-all-apps-page/

Th cause of the problem is unknown, but the icon might reappear if you copy the icon to the program folder again